# how do I array from a GET request function in viewdidload function in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, get

I'm very new to swift, so I will probably have a lot of faults in my code but what I'm trying to achieve is send a GET request to a server with paramters inside a function. I want to use the array I receive from the server in my viewdidload and in other functions but cant seem to find a way to store the array so i can use it. in my function it is filled, but out of my function it is empty

```
var scenarioArray: Array<Any> = []


let idPersoon = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "idPersoon") as! String

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
ScenarioArray()
print(scenarioArray)
print(self.scenarioArray)
}
func ScenarioArray()  {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://dtsl.ehb.be/app&web/ios_php/getAllScenariosByPersoon.php?persoonID="+idPersoon)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                self.scenarioArray = (jsonResult["Scenarios"] as! NSArray) as! Array<Any>
                print("ASynchronous\(self.scenarioArray)")

            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: try to append that data in array

Comment: Replace this line
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://dtsl.ehb.be/app&web/ios_php/getAllScenariosByPersoon.php?persoonID="+idPersoon)!)
   
With 
 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://dtsl.ehb.be/app&web/ios_php/getAllScenariosByPersoon.php?persoonID=\\(idPersoon)")

Comment: in Swift we simply use "\\(varName)" to get variable  value. " "+varName is not used in Swift to append value

Comment: Move the line `print(scenarioArray)` and everything you want to do afterwards from `viewDidLoad` into the completion block after `self.scenarioArray = ...`. By the way you don't need an URLRequest because GET the default. Just pass the URL to the data task. **And do not use NSArray / NSDictionary in Swift**

Comment: thanks! but how do i get the value in the viewdidload, in the function it is filled but when i call scenarioArray outside the function its empty

Comment: @AbhishekSharma `+idPersoon` is perfect valid syntax.

Comment: Once again, do the things you need to do (for example update the UI) in the (asynchronous) completion block. Think asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "problem" is that you are trying to GET data from a server, meaning that you are doing a network call.

Now...you don't know *how* long that network call will take when you launch it, if you are on a good network then it might be fast, but if you are on 3G network it might take a while.

If the call to your server was done synchronously, the result would be that  each and every time you'd try to fetch data your code would focus on doing just that, meaning that nothing else would go on... that is not what you want :)

Instead, when you use `URLSession`, and call `task.resume()` that method is executed asynchronously, meaning that it starts on another thread in the background where it will fetch data.

In the meantime, your main thread is free to handle UI rendering and so on. At some point in the near future your network call finishes and you now have valid data and must inform whoever needs to know.

So when you do a call to [dataTask(with: completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask), what you are actually saying is something along the lines of:

"hey...go fetch this data in the background please, and when you're done, I'd like to execute the code I've passed you here in the `completionHandler` with the parameters you tell me about".

Hope that makes just a little sense :)

Now...you have this code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            self.scenarioArray = (jsonResult["Scenarios"] as! NSArray) as! Array<Any>
            print("ASynchronous\(self.scenarioArray)")

        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

That last part of the function call (`{ data, response, error in...`) is the `completionHandler`, which is not executed straight away. It is not executed until the retrieval of data has completed.

And *therefore* when you do a call to your `ScenarioArray()` function in `viewDidLoad`, what will happen is that the asynchronous call to fetch data will start in the background and your `viewDidLoad` will continue what it is doing, meaning that when you say:

```
print(scenarioArray)
print(self.scenarioArray)
```

then you can not expect `scenarioArray` to be populated yet as your `task` is busy fetching that data in the background.

So...what you need to do, as @vadian says, is to update your UI *once the data has been fetched*, meaning, in the `completionHandler`.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    do {
        if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
            self.scenarioArray = (jsonResult["Scenarios"] as! NSArray) as! Array<Any>
            print("ASynchronous\(self.scenarioArray)")
            //Now you have data, reload the UI with the right scenarioArray
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you.