# Swift URLSession not working before making PageView

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, uipageviewcontroller, urlsession

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705278/swift-url-session-and-url-request-not-working), but I couldn't solve my problem.  
`DispatchQueue.main.async` code cannot work to my code.
I think my problem is a little bit different from that. So I post my question.

I have 3 views.

[image]

`FirstView` is a table view that user can select their choice.  
`SecondView` is a view that handles `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` and `DataSource`.  
`ThirdView` is a view which will be page views of `Second view`.  
(The view at the bottom is `PageViewController`)

When user selects and tap the button on the `First View`, it goes to the `Second view`.  
Then, `Second View` presents the result. (Actually, `Third View` shows the result, but it seems to be just shown in the `Second View`.)

The contents of the result are from the DB on server based on user's selection in the `FirstView`.

I thought that I need to fetched the result from server in the `SecondView` before presenting results on the `ThirdView`.

So I write the fetching code on the `viewDidLoad` in the `SecondView`'s `View Controller`.

Here's the data model code

```
struct MyData: Decodable {
let a: String
let b: String
let c: String
}
```

Here's the `Second View` class code

```
class SecondView: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, 
UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
let pageControl: UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
let pageControlHeight: CGFloat = 20

var passedFromFirstVC: [String] = []
var pageTitle: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://xxxxx.xxx/" )! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var postString = "xxxxxx"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let fetchedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyData].self, from: data)
            print(fetchedData)
            self.pageTitle.append(fetchedData[x].xx)

         } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
         }
    }
    task.resume()
```

And in `viewDidLoad` code, the `pageViewController` codes are there.  
Here's the residual codes in `viewDidLoad`.

```
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageviewcontroller") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as! ContentViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

And to make page index, this code is followed. Here's the code.

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController {

    let vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

    vc.pageIndex = index
    print("page just has been moved...")
    print(pageTitles)

    vc.titleText = pageTitles[index]
    return vc
}
```

But, when I run the app, it stops `vc.titleText = pageTitles[index]` in this code.  
Because, `pageTitles` are nil.

So I set a breakpoint on the `viewDidLoad`, and I found that `task` had not been compiled.

It ignores `task` and `task.resume()` code, and then complies the following codes.

So, `DispatchQueue.main.async` code cannot work to my code.

But, when I set certain initial value in `pageTitle`(even after `task.resume()`), then `task` had been compiled after compiling codes related to other `PageViewController`.

And, when I made this code in another project with a just single `ViewController`(not like my `PageViewController`), it also compiles `task` code in `viewDidLoad`.

Why `task` code in this question had not been compiled?

And, how can I fetch data before compiling page view controller code?

Comment: Your problem is not related to `URLSession`. I suppose your code crashing with `index our of range` error exception. Try to google it

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from comments from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613596/how-do-i-array-from-a-get-request-function-in-viewdidload-function-in-swift).
This is the comment.

> Move the line print(scenarioArray) and everything you want to do afterwards from viewDidLoad into the completion block after self.scenarioArray = ....

The point is 'put other codes in `viewDidLoad` into completion block(in this code, `do` block) by making `DispatchQueue.main.async { code }` in `do` block.

### Here's the answer.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    var request = URLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://xxxxx.xxx/" )! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    var postString = "xxxxxx"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
            return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let fetchedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyData].self, from: data)
                self.pageTitle.append(fetchedData[x].xx)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageviewcontroller") as! UIPageViewController
                    self.pageViewController.delegate = self
                    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
                    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
                    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) as! ContentViewController
                    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)
                    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
                    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
                    self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
                 }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
        }
    task.resume()
}
```

#### But, be aware of `view` in CGRect width and height code.

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
```

When you put this code in 'do' block, `view` will bring ambiguous error of.

Then modify that code to this.

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: self.pageViewController.view.frame.width, height: self.pageViewController.view.frame.height)
```

Hope this help!